# Approach for natural language understanding of RSS feeds

Tags: rss, nltk

I am currently working on a project involving RSS feeds. The objective is to understand exactly what it reports, for example, if there is an outbreak of violence, strike etc, it can be used to alert people near the scene of crime.

I am using nltk. Is using a classifier the most efficient way? What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Do you have example code? What have you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Are you going to analyze sentiment? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis

Comment: No I am not looking to analyze sentiment. I have tried using the feedparser and I also did sentence segmentation, tokenization and pos tagging.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. Are there preset categories in which you will categorize feeds, or is this more of a summarization task? You mention alerting people nearby, so do you need to extract locations from the RSS-feeds? Do you need temporal tagging or are your articles guaranteed to be about current events? Do you wish to identify entities mentioned in the feeds?
Because depending on your needs, the answers may vary wildly.

Comment: I have tried chunking to extract noun and verb phrases. I thought this will help me identify entities and events( i.e., what is happening to what). Yes, I would like to extract locations mentioned too. My articles are not guaranteed to be about current events so I would need temporal tagging. An event that has occured like for example, bomb blast, terror, outbreak of violent strikes harming people in vicinity would fit my category of interest.